# I have multiple dynamic checkboxes .I want to retrieve values inside function

Tags: javascript

> I have a form in which checkboxes are being created dynamically.I 
>                 want to 
>                  fetch the value of checked checkbox inside function.

```
         <label>

              <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' . $student .'   

               />&nbsp;<label for name=' . $student . '>' . $student . 
             '</label>

        </label>

       plz help me
```

Comment: $('[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){ alert($(this).val()) });

Comment: @JYoThl thnkuuu

Comment: glad to help @Ronny if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference

Comment: @JYoThl  can u tell me how i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: below i posted a answer on post left of post you can see tick mark . you can tick that . and it have time limit after that only you can able to tick it . check it now . let me know if you got it ? @Ronny

Comment: @Ronny tag the question with jquery if your accepting an answer where jquery is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple use **on change** and **each function** to get all checked check box values

```js
$(document).on('change','input[type=checkbox]' ,function(){
   var all=[];
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){ 

   all.push($(this).val());

});
console.log(all);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value='1'   />&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value='2'   />&nbsp;
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
$(function(){
$('[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
if($(this).attr('checked')==true)
{
var value=$(this).attr('value');
}
});
});

function form_values() { 
var jsvar = document.myform1.text_quest.value; 
alert(jsvar); // test 
var chk = []; 
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){ 
//alert($(this).val()); 
chk.push($(this).val()); 
}); alert(chk); 
}
```

Comment: function form_values()
    {

    var jsvar = document.myform1.text_quest.value;
    alert(jsvar); // test
   
    
      var chk = [];
   $(':radio:checked').each(function(){
         //alert($(this).val());
          chk.push($(this).val());
   });
   alert(chk); 
   
  $(function(){
   $('[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr('checked')==true)
   {
   var value=$(this).attr('value');
   alert(value);
   }
   });
   

    }

Comment: i edited and added the answer .check now your function

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwigltzo3f3TAhXHPI8KHTVbAi0QFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w) for dynamic checkbox value .And using with map and get() .to create the array values

```js
$(document).on('click','button' ,function(){
var a = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
  return $(this).val()
}).get()
console.log(a)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' . $student .'   />&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' . $student .'   />&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' . $student .'   />&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value=' . $student .'   />&nbsp;

<button>result click</button>
```